# Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater for ionic 2.1.8

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have just updated my local machine setup and now config of it is as -

---

```
******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68



******************************************************
```

Now i am getting error when i build for android (ionic build android) as-

Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Need help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got solution of this issue,

> It mean to say that I have older version of SDK, as per new setup it
>   need at-least SDK-1.8 to get run build of the application.

For that I downloaded new version of SDK [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
And then updated my SDK version using [this article](https://www.techonia.com/781/install-oracle-jdk-8-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite).

After that when I run this command-

```
ionic run android
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Ubuntu, you could do the following, too:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

That worked for me.

For more information about installing java/javac using update-alternatives, please refer to: [How do I make java default to a manually installed JRE/JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk)

Comment: THANK YOU! I want to add that this fixes ionic codorva run as well. The error message kept saying to update JAVA_HOME but I had already updated it!

Answer (score 1):

So I found that Ionic at the time of post-Cordova does not like JDK above 1.8.

1. To Solve get JDK 8.
2. Remove any JDK or JRE version higher than version 8 because it will automatically look for the highest version JDK the Java folder in c drive.

OR

1. Next solution is to just change what JDK Cordova looks for to version 8.

Comment: I found this related post very helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is my best option for my case, I use Cordova 6.2 version (not latest). I've worked with 1.7 Java as long as I can follow the technology from them. But since Cordova upgrade their system, now they prepare using 1.8 to implemented. If I not wrong, since 6.3 version their using that. I work in Snow Leopard with 1.7 java, it's hard to move on to upgrade my OS since I use old Macbook, I don't have several choice here.