# cordova run android with mac

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^5.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.

I am facing above issue while running

```
ionic cordova run android
```

on mac. not sure why its giving this issue. I am using android 6.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: run these commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file --force
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file@latest
ionic cordova run android
```

When you run `ionic cordova run android`, the Cordova CLI is running a `prepare` operation which tries to restore any plugins which are present in your `config.xml`/`package.json` but not installed in you local project.

So it's trying to install a recent version of `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` but this is failing because you have v4.3.3 of `cordova-plugin-file` installed in `plugins/` and `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` [now requires](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/plugin.xml#L32) v5.0.0+

Comment: Thanks @DaveAlden above issue is resolved. but now facing issue like

Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
and i have java version 
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

Comment: That's because [Android and therefore Cordova doesn't support Java 9 yet](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11343). Potential solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46807676/777265).