# can't bluid cordova app: java Requirements check failed for JDK

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic3

I trid to build an app with cordova ionic 3, but I got the error :Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.2. But I have version 9 install... here info:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\android
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

C:\...>ionic info

cli packages: (C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 windows 5.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.0.1
Node              : v9.0.0
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : C:\android

Misc:

backend : pro
```

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater

Comment: add version 8 instead of 9.. now getting this error: Error: Unhandled error. (The platform "cordova" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. cordova not supported.)

Comment: follow another post taht suggest to rm and re add android platform ... now getting: > cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\android
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Answer (score 2):

unstall any java sdk you have Install JDK 1.8  follow this link
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html   and then look for  Java SE Development Kit 8u172 and accept aggreement then download it.  and then change your enviroment variable to match the java sdk location e.g JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was install 1.8 then not naming environment path "...\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin" but "...\Java\jdk1.8.0_161"

Answer (score 0):

put the other versions of JDK in a other folder and:

sudo -s

apt-get install gradle

[ionic 2 - Error Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480076/ionic-2-error-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android)