# Cordova error: requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Tags: android, windows, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I had installed JDK 10.0.1 on my pc with windows 10 and I tried to build an app with `ionic Cordova build android --prod -- release`.

But I got the warning:

> Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater.

I checked the environmental variables and they seem to be correct. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova : Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater)