# Apache Cordova : Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8

Tags: java, cordova

Good day! I was trying Apache Cordova and encountered the following:

```
C:\Users\peepo\CordovaProjects\HelloWorld>cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\peepo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8

C:\Users\peepo\CordovaProjects\HelloWorld>java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I've tried what have been suggested in [Cordova : Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater)

- Uninstall JDK 1.8 versions and install only latest JDK 1.8
- Exported JAVA_HOME in USER and/or SYSTEM variable in ENV variables

But the error persists.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: on `cmd` type `where java` to see actual java path.

Answer (score 0):

After few tries, I was able to find a solution.

I have a java 1.7 declared in SYS variable, I've replaced it with the java 1.8 version.