# Cordova running android emulator

Tags: cordova, console

I have a error in my console with cordova when i do "cordova run android". I add android emulator with the console before 
"cordova platform add android" but I have this error. Thank you for take your time to answer.

Error : 
cordova run android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\psegado\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater)

Comment: Thank you Mstoner