# Running Android emulator from Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to run an Android emulator in my mac from the Ionic project through the command prompt. I have all setup of the android studio and its running well. However, when I try to generate the emulator I am unable to do it from the ionic terminal project. I am thrown with the following errors.

> Cordova build android
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/mac/Library/Android/SDK (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mac/Library/Android/SDK (DEPRECATED)
> Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 14.0.1
> Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess Cordova.

Comment: Did you added enviornment variable?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Android works with java 1.8. You seem to have a higher version installed in your system.

Try to installing Java 1.8 and set the JAVA_HOME to java 1.8.
This link could help you: [Cordova : Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater/41161490)