# Ionic : I can't run ionic app into my device

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, device

I have been trying to run my sample ionic application into my actual android device.

I kept on getting this error. Please have a look and tell me how to fix it.

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\FNSV\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\FNSV\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 16
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova : Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628240/cordova-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater)

Comment: change your JDK version to `1.8.*`.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot run into my device if I use JDK 16?